# Created nuget package's dll can not be accessable from package's loaded project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I want to create a nuget package of my .net core class library.

1. I copied the nuget.exe file to the root folder of my Solution
2. Run nuget spec and Solution.nuspec file created. I modified it as below:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <package >
   <metadata>
   <id>Solution</id>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
   <authors>cc Team</authors>
   <owners>cc</owners>
   <licenseUrl></licenseUrl>
   <projectUrl></projectUrl>
   <iconUrl></iconUrl>
   <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
   <description></description>
   <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
   <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
   <tags>c# .net</tags>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" />
   </dependencies>
   <references>
       <reference file="Solution.dll" />
   </references>
   </metadata>
   <files>
   <file src="Solution.dll" target="lib\netstandard1.6\Solution.dll"/>
   ```

file's node src value outpupath of my solution. (bin\Release\netstandard1.6\Solution.dll)

1. Run nuget pack Solution.nuspec and  Solution.nupkg file created.
2. I put it to my package source.
3. Create a new .net core class library and select my Solution nuget package from local package source. It added to my project. There is no error or warning. But When I try to access a class from my Solution nuget package, it couldn't be found.I dowloaded  'Nuget Package Explorer' and opened my Solution.nupkg. Icould see Solution.dll and Solution.pdb file under lib --> netstandart1.6.

Then I searched about the error and found this :

```
"scripts": {
"postcompile": [
  "dotnet pack --no-build --configuration %compile:Configuration%"
]
}
```

After compile my Solution project it creates Solution.1.0.0-0.nupkg file and Solution.1.0.0-0.symbols. I put it to my local package source but these packages are not listed in the 'Nuget Package Manager'.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

My experience is creating package from solution sometimes crappy. Creating the package from the project file could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After I clean 'C:\Users\XXX.nuget\packages\Solution' folder and add package again fix my problem.

Because there is bad formatted nutget package which I tried before.